# Prebuilt libraries not found for sharp while generating Gatsby starter

Tags: npm, gatsby, sharp

I try to generate a [Gatsby blog starter](https://github.com/tomoyukikashiro/gatsby-starter-blog-amp-to-pwa) using following command:

```
npx gatsby new my-blog-starter https://github.com/tomoyukikashiro/gatsby-starter-blog-amp-to-pwa
```

While `npm install` is running the `sharp` thirdparty does not find its prebuilt binaries. Because of this it will be tried to be built on my PC, but it fails with following error.

```
info Installing packages...

> sharp@0.21.3 install C:\Repositories\my-blog-starter\node_modules\sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Using cached C:\Users\Milan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_libvips\libvips-8.7.0-win32-x64.tar.gz
info sharp Creating C:\Repositories\my-blog-starter\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
info sharp Copying DLLs from C:\Repositories\my-blog-starter\node_modules\sharp\vendor\lib to C:\Repositories\my-blog-st
arter\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=12.17.0 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=win32)

C:\Repositories\my-blog-starter\node_modules\sharp>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nod
e_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (nod
e "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
  VError.cpp
  VInterpolate.cpp
  VImage.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
     Creating library C:\Repositories\my-blog-starter\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\libvips-cpp.lib and object C:\Re
  positories\my-blog-starter\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\libvips-cpp.exp
  libvips-cpp.vcxproj -> C:\Repositories\my-blog-starter\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\\libvips-cpp.dll
  common.cc
  metadata.cc
  stats.cc
  operations.cc
C:\Repositories\my-blog-starter\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(356,37): error C2660: 'v8::StringObject::N
ew': function does not take 1 arguments (compiling source file ..\src\metadata.cc) [C:\Repositories\my-blog-starter\nod
e_modules\sharp\build\sharp.vcxproj]
```

Environment:

- Node.js version `12.17.0`
- npm version `6.14.4`
- npx version `10.2.2`
- There is no corporate proxy that would block the requests for the prebuilt binaries.

Are there any tips, how can I solve this issue? For me it is also fine to build the thirdparty locally, but I don't see exactly what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your starter requires `sharp` version `0.21.3` (as shown in your error log)

Node 12 support on windows was [introduced](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1668#issuecomment-497448183) in version `0.22.1`.

You could try upgrading `gatsby-plugin-sharp` and `gatsby-transformer-sharp` in your starter, but you might encounter other errors, as the starter hasn't been updated for a while.